# AngularJS Running a piece of code on app load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Groundwork:

- I have a handful of AngularJS applications that for the most part act as a single app.
- All of the apps uses AngularUIRouter
- I have an angular service built which will show a pop-up alert on-screen that we use all over the codebase. `alertService.danger("You broke it!")`
- Those are great and stay up through page changes when you are not jumping between top-level angularjs apps which causes a hard refresh.
- But if you make a call to show alert, and then immediately redirect to another app, the alert is lost.

So... I want to, ON APP LOAD (refresh), detect if there are URL parameters "?alertMessage=You Broke it&alertType=Danger" and if so, call my service to show the alert based on what's passed.

I'm wondering what the best way to achieve this is. I created a factory like this:

```
#alertOnLoad.js
var AlertOnLoad = angular.module('myApp.alertOnLoad.service', []);

AlertOnLoad.factory('alertOnLoad', function($location, alertService) {
  var queryParams = $location.search();
  var alertText = queryParams.alertText;
  var alertType = queryParams.alertType;

  alertService[alertType](alertText, {timeout: 3000});
  return {};
});

module.exports = AlertOnLoad.name;
```

Then in my App.js I inject that service. So it gets run on page load.

```
#app.js
angular.module('myApp.onOfMyApps', [
  viewsModule,
  scaffoldingModule
])

.config(function($locationProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled: true
  });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/asset-list/');
})
.run(function($rootScope, alertOnLoad){ // Service Injected here

});
```

This totally works but it feels wrong for a few reasons:

- For one it's setup as a factory but I'm not returning any methods in the object. That seems weird.
- It seems weird to be injecting dependencies into the `app.run()` block just to get them to kick off on setup.

I'm curious if anyone has any other thoughts on how to better utilize Angular to achieve this.

Cheers!

Comment: Can't your `AlertOnLoad` app have its own `.run()` block?

Comment: app.run () will load the function as soon as the app is run, Then you can use $routeParams to check if there are any parameters passed.

Comment: @JCFord Factories don't have an $onLoad() method but I could add my own run() function. But then that would mean I'd have to call it in the run block which just adds more work for no value.

Comment: The purpose of the `.run()` function is exactly what you're trying to achieve. I don't understand your objection to using it. My comment was essentially that it should be done entirely in a run block and it belongs in the alert module.